# Nesting multiple same select queries and reuse without second round trip to database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a rows with two different IDs in database. Now I am trying to show two different data columns in one row, I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([Participant].[Stake]) AS [PlayerStake],
    (SELECT [dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([Stake]) 
     FROM [dbo].[Participant_Complete] 
     WHERE [ParticipantId] = [Fold].[HouseParticipantId]) AS [HouseStake],
    ([dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([Participant].[Stake]) + [dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([C].[RunningWinLoss])) AS [PlayerStakeAfterRound],
    (SELECT [dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([Stake]) 
     FROM [dbo].[Participant_Complete] 
     WHERE [ParticipantId] = [Fold].[HouseParticipantId]) - [dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([C].[RunningWinLoss]) AS [HouseStakeAfterRound]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Round_Complete] AS [C]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Fold_Complete] AS [Fold] ON [Fold].[Id] = [C].[Id]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Participant_Complete] AS [Participant] ON [Participant].[ParticipantId] = [Fold].[PlayerParticipantId]
```

This works, but as you can see it will do two trips to database for same nested select. How can I make this only one round trip?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  You are executing one query.  That is one round trip to the database.  Where are you getting multiple "round trips"?

Comment: There are two nested selects practically the same. Can I do this with one nested select so I avoid repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the subqueries.  That is not a "round trip to the database", which usually refers to an application calling a query.

All the square braces make the query hard to read, but you can fix this using `apply`:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fnHexToNumber](p.[Stake]) AS PlayerStake,
       h.HouseStake,
       ([dbo].[fnHexToNumber](p.[Stake]) + [dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([C].RunningWinLoss)) AS PlayerStakeAfterRound,
        (h.HouseStake - [dbo].fnHexToNumber(C.RunningWinLoss)) AS HouseStakeAfterRound
FROM [dbo].[Round_Complete] c JOIN
     [dbo].[Fold_Complete] f
     ON f.[Id] = c.[Id] JOIN
     [dbo].[Participant_Complete] pc
     ON px.[ParticipantId] = f.[PlayerParticipantId] OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT [dbo].[fnHexToNumber]([Stake]) as HouseStake
      FROM [dbo].[Participant_Complete] pch
      WHERE pch.ParticipantId = f.HouseParticipantId
     ) h
```

Comment: is outer apply faster than inner join?

Comment: @sensie . . . They are not exactly comparable.  `OUTER APPY` is equivalent to `LEFT JOIN`.  Both methods are reasonable, but this calls the function `fnHexToNumber()` only once for the house stake.  That should be a performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

Just join the same table a second time instead of pulling the data as sub-queries.

Also, you only need brackets around names if the names contain a space (which is bad practice in general). If the names don't have a space, the brackets are totally extraneous.

```
SELECT
    dbo.fnHexToNumber(Participant.Stake) AS PlayerStake,
    dbo.fnHexToNumber(p.Stake) as HouseStake,
    (dbo.fnHexToNumber(Participant.Stake) + dbo.fnHexToNumber(C.RunningWinLoss)) AS PlayerStakeAfterRound,
    dbo.fnHexToNumber(p.Stake) - dbo.fnHexToNumber(c.RunningWinLoss) as HouseStakeAfterRound
FROM dbo.Round_Complete AS C
INNER JOIN dbo.Fold_Complete AS Fold 
    ON Fold.Id = C.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Participant_Complete AS Participant 
    ON Participant.ParticipantId = Fold.PlayerParticipantId
INNER JOIN dbo.Participant_Complete AS p 
    ON p.ParticipantId = Fold.HouseParticipantId
```